# Batch insert/update via contentProvider based on 2 fields

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, batch-insert, batch-updates

i'm creating a contentProvider , and i wish to be able to send it multiple DB records (contentValues) to be inserted or updated to a single table using a single batch operations .

how do i do that?

batchInsert is intended only for inserting , but wouldn't it mean that insertion of something that already exists won't do anything?

also , is there a way for the update operation to use a special constraint ? for example , i need to ignore the primary key and update based on 2 other fields that together are unique.

Answer (score 0):

"batchInsert is intended only for inserting" : this is true BUT you can override it in your ContentProvider to perform an UPSERT (insert/update) depending on the URI passed to batchInsert.

The following is some working code that I currently use to perform bulk inserts on time-series data (admittedly, I just delete anything that gets in the way instead of updating, but you could easily change this to your own ends.).

Also note the use of the sql transaction; this speeds up the process immensely.

```
    @Override
public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] values) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
    switch (match(uri)) {
    case ONEPROGRAMME:
        String cid = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        int insertCount = 0;
        int len = values.length;
        if (len > 0) {
            long start = values[0].getAsLong(Programme.COLUMN_START);
            long end = values[len - 1].getAsLong(Programme.COLUMN_END);
            String where = Programme.COLUMN_CHANNEL + "=? AND " + Programme.COLUMN_START + ">=? AND "
                    + Programme.COLUMN_END + "<=?";
            String[] args = { cid, Long.toString(start), Long.toString(end) };
            //TODO use a compiled statement ?
            //SQLiteStatement stmt = sqlDB.compileStatement(INSERT)
            sqlDB.beginTransaction();
            try {
                sqlDB.delete(tableName(PROGRAMME_TABLE), where, args);
                for (ContentValues row : values) {
                    if (sqlDB.insert(tableName(PROGRAMME_TABLE), null, row) != -1L) {
                        insertCount++;
                    }
                }
                sqlDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } finally {
                sqlDB.endTransaction();
            }
        }
        if (insertCount > 0)
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(Resolver.PROGRAMME.uri, null);
        return insertCount;

    default:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: sadly this was a very long time ago. don't remember what it's about and how i handled it. sorry.